# Pivot data with mulitple columns (Col1, Col2, Col3) per record (Row1, Row2, Row3) to Row per Col

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

So I have data that is set up like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person | Info1 | Info2 | Info3 | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
| Person1 | 10-12 | M | green | ball | truck | book |
| Person2 | 3-5 | M | yellow | necklace | doll | stroller |

and I want it to look like:

| Person | Info1 | Info2 | Info3 | Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | 10-12 | M | green | ball |
| Person1 | 10-12 | M | green | truck |
| Person1 | 10-12 | M | green | book |
| Person2 | 3-5 | M | yellow | necklace |
| Person2 | 3-5 | M | yellow | doll |
| Person2 | 3-5 | M | yellow | stroller |

In a database I could union three sets of data, something like:

Select Person, Info1, Info2, Info3, Item1 as Item from mytable
union
Select Person, Info1, Info2, Info3, Item2 as Item from mytable
union
Select Person, Info1, Info2, Info3, Item3 as Item from mytable

Any suggestions on how I might accomplish this in Google Sheets?

I was thinking I would use a pivot but the issue I encountered is that I need to reference three different columns as one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert specific columns into rows in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446888/convert-specific-columns-into-rows-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

You can use REDUCE to iterate over the items and grab the A:D columns based on the row of the item:

```
=REDUCE(HSTACK(A1:D1,"Item"),E2:G,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="",a,
VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX(A:D,ROW(v)),v)))))
```

[image]